# deploy a csproj file in c# project?

Tags: c#, html, csproj

I added 3 html files to my project and the change is reflected in my csproj file.

But to deploy this on to a web server, is it enough if I drop these 3 files in the appropriate directory? Or is there any build/assembly deploy needed because of csproj change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Html files do not require build, just copy the files
IF you have code behind for aspx files then you need to deploy the dll.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add the file to your project.
2. Set the build action to "content".
3. Set "copy to output directory" to "copy always".
4. The file should be included in the same folder as the rest of your deployment. You should be able to see it by building it and looking in the `\bin\release` or the `\bin\debug` folder. If it's not there, click on the Application Files button and see if it shows up there.

Answer (score 1):

Deploying the HTML files to your web server simply requires you copy the HTML files to the appropriate directory.

The resulting change in your .csproj was really only made to keep track of the files within your IDE but no, you wouldn't need to rebuild/redeploy the resulting DLL just for static files.